# Downgrade Gedit in Fedora 23

Tags: fedora, gedit

I am running Fedora 23 and need to downgrade to gedit 3.10.4 and the corresponding versions of `gedit-plugins` and `gedit-r-plugin`.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/766056/2413) provides code to do this in ubuntu. I'm trying to do the same thing in Fedora 23.

## Edit:

I summarize all the commands from Serge's answer below (and the ones in the comments). From a clean install of F23, I do:

```
sudo dnf install @development-tools fedora-packager rpmdevtools
sudo /usr/sbin/useradd makerpm
sudo usermod -a -G mock makerpm
sudo passwd makerpm
```

(then I assign a password to user makerpm and log out and log in as makerpm).
Then, I download gedit-3.10.4 from Fedora archives (link in Serge's answer).
Then

```
su -
cd /home/makerpm/
cd Download
sh downgradgedit.sh
```

Now, I get:

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# sh downgradgedit.sh
warning: gedit-3.10.4-1.fc20.src.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 246110c1: NOKEY
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
(Stripping trailing CRs from patch; use --binary to disable.)
patching file gedit.spec
downgradgedit.sh: line 32: $'\r': command not found
error: Failed build dependencies:
    autoconf is needed by gedit-2:3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64
    automake is needed by gedit-2:3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64
    enchant-devel >= 1.2.0 is needed by gedit-2:3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64
    glib2-devel >= 2.37.5 is needed by gedit-2:3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64
    gnome-common is needed by gedit-2:3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64
    gobject-introspection-devel is needed by gedit-2:3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64
    gsettings-desktop-schemas-devel is needed by gedit-2:3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64
    gtk3-devel is needed by gedit-2:3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64
    gtksourceview3-devel >= 3.9.91 is needed by gedit-2:3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64
    intltool is needed by gedit-2:3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64
    iso-codes-devel >= 0.35 is needed by gedit-2:3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64
    itstool is needed by gedit-2:3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64
    libSM-devel is needed by gedit-2:3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64
    libattr-devel is needed by gedit-2:3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64
    libpeas-devel >= 1.7.0 is needed by gedit-2:3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64
    libtool is needed by gedit-2:3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64
    pygobject3-devel is needed by gedit-2:3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64
    python3-devel is needed by gedit-2:3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64
    yelp-tools is needed by gedit-2:3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64
    zeitgeist-devel >= 0.9.12 is needed by gedit-2:3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64
```

so that I:

```
dnf install autoconf automake enchant-devel glib2-devel gnome-common gobject-introspection-devel gsettings-desktop-schemas-devel gtk3-devel gtksourceview3-devel intltool iso-codes-devel itstool libSM-devel libattr-devel libpeas-devel libtool pygobject3-devel python3-devel yelp-tools zeitgeist-devel
```

then, I `sh downgradgedit.sh` (this time exit without a problem):

```
Executing(%clean): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.PxbsBL
+ umask 022
+ cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ cd gedit-3.10.4
+ /usr/bin/rm -rf /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/gedit-3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64
+ exit 0
```

Next, do:

```
su -
cd 
sudo dnf install ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/gedit-3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64.rpm
sudo dnf install ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/geditdevel3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64.rpm.
```

After that cd to directory where you have `gedit-plugins-3.10.1-1.fc20.src.rpm`:

```
cd /home/makerpm/Downloads/
sudo yum-builddep gedit-plugins-3.10.1-1.fc20.src.rpm
rpmbuild --rebuild gedit-plugins-3.10.1-1.fc20.src.rpm
```

Then do

```
sudo dnf install ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/gedit-plugins-3.10.1-1.fc23.x86_64.rpm
```

now launching `gedit` launches the desired version of `gedit`. The `terminal-plugin` is even visible in the list of plugins. But activating it causes:

```
GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile' does not contain a key named 'word-chars'
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1):

Prepare your system as described here: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package#Preparing_your_system

Log in as a build user and download the source rpm of gedit-3.10.4 from Fedora archives: http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/updates/20/SRPMS/gedit-3.10.4-1.fc20.src.rpm

install any build dependencies:

```
$ sudo yum-builddep gedit-3.10.4-1.fc20.src.rpm
```

and build the binary rpm:

```
$ rpmbuild --rebuild gedit-3.10.4-1.fc20.src.rpm
```

Your binary packages would be in `~/rpmbuild/RPMS/<arch>` folder

Repeat the source download and rebuild for any other packages you need.

You can omit the creation of a special user for builds and make everything using your own account if you wish.

**Edit:** 
Obviously, while building plugins you will need the development packages of gedit-3.10.4 to be installed. So before resolving deps with yum-builddep for plugins src rpm, install the devel packages you will get from gedit rebuild.

**Edit2:**

According to the discussion in comments, the just built gedit-3.10.4-1 does not work due to incompatibility with recent versions of `gnome`. Here is the script that applies the patch for commit https://github.com/GNOME/gedit/commit/3bed781fca0f128d0c960f095aca3dfd30c0923d with rejects fixed.

```
#!/bin/bash
rpm -i gedit-3.10.4-1.fc20.src.rpm || exit 1
patch -d ~/rpmbuild/SPECS -p0 <<'EOF'
--- gedit.spec.orig 2014-07-21 18:27:05.000000000 +0400
+++ gedit.spec  2016-06-03 01:27:32.294149403 +0300
@@ -25,7 +25,7 @@
 Name:      gedit
 Epoch:     2
 Version:   3.10.4
-Release:   1%{?dist}
+Release:   1.local%{?dist}
 License:   GPLv2+ and GFDL
 Group:     Applications/Editors
 #VCS: git:git://git.gnome.org/gedit
@@ -41,6 +41,7 @@
 %endif

 Patch4: gedit-disable-python3.patch
+Patch999: gedit-remove-enable-delete.patch

 BuildRequires: gnome-common
 BuildRequires: glib2-devel >= %{glib2_version}
@@ -124,6 +125,7 @@
 %if !%{with_python3}
 %patch4 -p1 -b .disable-python
 %endif
+%patch999 -p1 -b .remove-enable-delete

 autoreconf -i -f
 intltoolize -f
EOF

cat >~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/gedit-remove-enable-delete.patch <<'EOF'
From 3bed781fca0f128d0c960f095aca3dfd30c0923d Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Paolo Borelli <pborelli@gnome.org>
Date: Tue, 3 Mar 2015 09:05:46 +0100
Subject: [PATCH] Remove checking nautilus "enable-delete" setting

Nautilus removed this setting
---
 plugins/filebrowser/gedit-file-browser-plugin.c    | 15 ---------
 plugins/filebrowser/gedit-file-browser-widget.c    | 36 +---------------------
 ...ome.gedit.plugins.filebrowser.gschema.xml.in.in |  3 --
 3 files changed, 1 insertion(+), 53 deletions(-)

diff --git a/plugins/filebrowser/gedit-file-browser-plugin.c b/plugins/filebrowser/gedit-file-browser-plugin.c
index 412757b..62c932f 100644
--- a/plugins/filebrowser/gedit-file-browser-plugin.c
+++ b/plugins/filebrowser/gedit-file-browser-plugin.c
@@ -52,7 +52,6 @@
 #define NAUTILUS_BASE_SETTINGS     "org.gnome.nautilus.preferences"
 #define NAUTILUS_FALLBACK_SETTINGS "org.gnome.gedit.plugins.filebrowser.nautilus"
 #define NAUTILUS_CLICK_POLICY_KEY  "click-policy"
-#define NAUTILUS_ENABLE_DELETE_KEY "enable-delete"
 #define NAUTILUS_CONFIRM_TRASH_KEY "confirm-trash"

 #define TERMINAL_BASE_SETTINGS     "org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal"
@@ -72,7 +71,6 @@ struct _GeditFileBrowserPluginPrivate
    gboolean        confirm_trash;

    guint           click_policy_handle;
-   guint           enable_delete_handle;
    guint           confirm_trash_handle;
 };

@@ -354,13 +352,6 @@ install_nautilus_prefs (GeditFileBrowserPlugin *plugin)
                  G_CALLBACK (on_click_policy_changed),
                  plugin);

-   /* Bind enable-delete */
-   g_settings_bind (priv->nautilus_settings,
-            NAUTILUS_ENABLE_DELETE_KEY,
-            priv->tree_widget,
-            "enable-delete",
-            G_SETTINGS_BIND_GET | G_SETTINGS_BIND_SET);
-
    /* Get confirm_trash */
    prefb = g_settings_get_boolean (priv->nautilus_settings,
                    NAUTILUS_CONFIRM_TRASH_KEY);
@@ -599,12 +590,6 @@ gedit_file_browser_plugin_deactivate (GeditWindowActivatable *activatable)
                         priv->click_policy_handle);
    }

-   if (priv->enable_delete_handle)
-   {
-       g_signal_handler_disconnect (priv->nautilus_settings,
-                        priv->enable_delete_handle);
-   }
-
    if (priv->confirm_trash_handle)
    {
        g_signal_handler_disconnect (priv->nautilus_settings,
diff --git a/plugins/filebrowser/gedit-file-browser-widget.c b/plugins/filebrowser/gedit-file-browser-widget.c
index 72a3da6..bd5a2d7 100644
--- a/plugins/filebrowser/gedit-file-browser-widget.c
+++ b/plugins/filebrowser/gedit-file-browser-widget.c
@@ -65,7 +65,6 @@ enum
    PROP_0,

    PROP_FILTER_PATTERN,
-   PROP_ENABLE_DELETE
 };

 /* Signals */
@@ -152,15 +151,11 @@ struct _GeditFileBrowserWidgetPrivate
    GtkWidget *location_next_menu;
    GtkWidget *current_location_menu_item;

-   gboolean enable_delete;
-
    GCancellable *cancellable;

    GdkCursor *busy_cursor;
 };

-static void set_enable_delete             (GeditFileBrowserWidget *obj,
-                       gboolean                enable);
 static void on_model_set                       (GObject                *gobject,
                        GParamSpec             *arg1,
                        GeditFileBrowserWidget *obj);
@@ -439,9 +434,6 @@ gedit_file_browser_widget_get_property (GObject   *object,
        case PROP_FILTER_PATTERN:
            g_value_set_string (value, obj->priv->filter_pattern_str);
            break;
-       case PROP_ENABLE_DELETE:
-           g_value_set_boolean (value, obj->priv->enable_delete);
-           break;
        default:
            G_OBJECT_WARN_INVALID_PROPERTY_ID (object, prop_id, pspec);
            break;
@@ -462,9 +454,6 @@ gedit_file_browser_widget_set_property (GObject     *object,
            gedit_file_browser_widget_set_filter_pattern (obj,
                                                          g_value_get_string (value));
            break;
-       case PROP_ENABLE_DELETE:
-           set_enable_delete (obj, g_value_get_boolean (value));
-           break;
        default:
            G_OBJECT_WARN_INVALID_PROPERTY_ID (object, prop_id, pspec);
            break;
@@ -489,13 +478,6 @@ gedit_file_browser_widget_class_init (GeditFileBrowserWidgetClass *klass)
                                  "The filter pattern",
                                  "",
                                  G_PARAM_READWRITE));
-   g_object_class_install_property (object_class, PROP_ENABLE_DELETE,
-                    g_param_spec_boolean ("enable-delete",
-                                  "Enable delete",
-                                  "Enable permanently deleting items",
-                                  TRUE,
-                                  G_PARAM_READWRITE |
-                                  G_PARAM_CONSTRUCT));

    signals[LOCATION_ACTIVATED] =
        g_signal_new ("location-activated",
@@ -795,19 +777,6 @@
    gtk_combo_box_set_active (GTK_COMBO_BOX (obj->priv->combo), 0);
 }

-static void
-set_enable_delete (GeditFileBrowserWidget *obj,
-          gboolean                enable)
-{
-   GAction *action;
-   obj->priv->enable_delete = enable;
-
-   action = g_simple_action_group_lookup (obj->priv->action_group,
-                                          "delete");
-
-   g_simple_action_set_enabled (G_SIMPLE_ACTION (action), enable);
-}
-
 static gboolean
 filter_real (GeditFileBrowserStore  *model,
         GtkTreeIter            *iter,
@@ -1036,8 +1005,6 @@ gedit_file_browser_widget_init (GeditFileBrowserWidget *obj)
                                    "browser",
                                    G_ACTION_GROUP (obj->priv->action_group));

-   set_enable_delete (obj, obj->priv->enable_delete);
-
    gtk_widget_init_template (GTK_WIDGET (obj));

    g_signal_connect (obj->priv->previous_button, "button-press-event",
@@ -2967,8 +2934,7 @@ on_treeview_key_press_event (GeditFileBrowserView   *treeview,
        event->keyval == GDK_KEY_KP_Delete)
    {

-       if ((event->state & modifiers) == GDK_SHIFT_MASK &&
-           obj->priv->enable_delete)
+       if ((event->state & modifiers) == GDK_SHIFT_MASK)
        {
            delete_selected_files (obj, FALSE);
            return TRUE;
diff --git a/plugins/filebrowser/org.gnome.gedit.plugins.filebrowser.gschema.xml.in.in b/plugins/filebrowser/org.gnome.gedit.plugins.filebrowser.gschema.xml.in.in
index cc76ab8..7a384c7 100644
--- a/plugins/filebrowser/org.gnome.gedit.plugins.filebrowser.gschema.xml.in.in
+++ b/plugins/filebrowser/org.gnome.gedit.plugins.filebrowser.gschema.xml.in.in
@@ -51,9 +51,6 @@
     <key name="click-policy" enum="org.gnome.gedit.plugins.filebrowser.nautilus.ClickPolicy">
       <default>'double'</default>
     </key>
-    <key name="enable-delete" type="b">
-      <default>false</default>
-    </key>
     <key name="confirm-trash" type="b">
       <default>true</default>
     </key>
EOF
rpmbuild -ba ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/gedit.spec
```

The script assumes that the `gedit-3.10.4-1.fc20.src.rpm` is in the current directory. After the build you'll find the binary packages in `~/rpmbuild/RPMS` directory as well as new, patched `SRPM` in `~/rpmbuild/SRPMS`

After doing the same steps in a chrooted FC23 installation I have no problems with terminal plugin:

[image]

**Edit 3**:

as the OP has issues with procedure I created a github repo with build script and resulting `RPM`s: https://github.com/geditFC23/gedit-3.10.4-fc23/releases

Comment: then download the plugin source 3.10.1 from archives. Edit clarification: The plugins are build provided an API defined by 'core' gedit component. It must be available as one of resulting RPMs from gedit build and should be named gedit-devel-3.10.4.fc23.<arch>.rpm. You need to install this RPM in order to build any plugin RPMs.

Comment: `sudo dnf install gedit-3.10.4-1.fc23.x86_64.rpm gedit-devel-3.10.4-1.fc23.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: without details on failure I can't help you

Comment: It seems you need to patch 3.10.4 with a fix from 3.16, see https://tracker.tanglu.org/T115 for details why. There is a link to the relevant commit. However, this could not be the only issue to run 3.10.4 under FC23. BTW, why do you need all this?

Comment: Are you capable to make patched version yourself?

Comment: Check the Edit #2, please

Comment: no, it is not. may be the site formatting spoils the things. The same at pastebin: http://pastebin.com/raw/2vbCBQKP

Comment: Ok, with the pastbin version and doing `sh downgradgedit.sh` the script works. Now I do have `gedit-3.10.4-1.local.fc23.src.rpm` in `~/rpmbuild/SRPMS`  but when I do `sudo dnf install gedit-3.10.4-1.local.fc23.src.rpm` I get `Last metadata expiration check performed 0:16:56 ago on Sun Jun  5 15:50:26 2016.
Error: Will not install a source rpm package (gedit-2:3.10.4-1.local.fc23.src).`

Comment: you need not to install gedit-3.10.4-1.local.fc23.src.rpm. It is a source package with patch included. You could keep it and use later in `rpmbuild --rebuld` command without tricks. Is the problem with unknown setting gone when you start gedit?

Comment: you need to uninstall gedit-3.18.1 and install your gedit-3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64.rpm package. Also, you need to add `exclude gedit-*`  to `/etc/yum.conf` so it will not be updated when you do `yum update`

Comment: So, I have `sudo yum remove gedit`, then run your script, then I go into `~/rpmbuild/SRPMS`, then I do `sudo rpmbuild --rebuild gedit-3.10.4-1.local.fc23.src.rpm` then I do `gedit` in the terminal and get: `bash: gedit: command not found...
Install package 'gedit' to provide command 'gedit'? [N/y] `

Comment: No. as I got, you already build the patched version. check your rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64 directory for binary rpms. just install them after current gedit removal

Comment: Ok, Almost there! From a clean install, I run your script, then `sudo yum remove gedit` go into `/home/kaveh/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64`, then `sudo dnf install gedit-3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64.rpm gedit-debuginfo-3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64.rpm gedit-devel-3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64.rpm gedit-zeitgeist-3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64.rpm` and now `gedit` launches `gedit-3.10.4` (Yahoo!). But how do I install `gedit-plugins_3.10.1` ?

Comment: As I wrote in the answer: download the source from archives: http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/updates/20/SRPMS/gedit-plugins-3.10.1-1.fc20.src.rpm and rebuild it with `rpmbuild --rebuild`

Comment: `sudo yum-builddep gedit-plugins-3.10.1-1.fc20.src.rpm`

Comment: terminal plugin is not a separate package on FC20 - it is a part of gedit-plugins package. are you sure you installed the ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/gedit-plugins-3.10.1-1.fc23.x86_64.rpm?

Comment: You were right, I didnt. So when I did install `~/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/gedit-plugins-3.10.1-1.fc23.x86_64.rpm`, I saw the Terminal plugin option, is now available. I enabled it and this caused gedit to crash. Now when I launch gedit I get: `GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile' does not contain a key named 'word-chars'
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)`. I will restart tomorrow on a fresh install of fedora23, but would you know what part I did wrong?

Comment: You did nothing wrong. Just the 3.10.1-1 of plugins is out of sync with FC23's gnome as well. Some patchwork required

Comment: I repeated the steps in FC23 chrooted installation and I do not see the same problem. See the edit.

Comment: Dear Serge, I think I am not doing this in the right order. I put in an edit to the question all the steps I do from a clean install of f23. Could yoou comment?

Comment: then do `sudo dnf install ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/gedit{,-devel}-3.10.4-1.local.fc23.x86_64.rpm`. After that cd to directory where you have gedit-plugins-3.10.1-1.fc20.src.rpm and do `sudo yum-builddep gedit-plugins-3.10.1-1.fc20.src.rpm` and `rpmbuild --rebuild gedit-plugins-3.10.1-1.fc20.src.rpm`. Then do `sudo dnf install ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/gedit-plugins-3.10.1-1.fc23.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: ;( I followed all instructions. I can see gedit is now the old version (Jey!) and that the terminal-plugin is in the list of plugins (Jey!!) but when I actvivate it, I still get `(gedit:16470): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile' does not contain a key named 'word-chars' Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)`. I will add your comment above to the edits of the main question so it is not lost in a long comment threat~

Comment: if you like I could share the packages I created.

Comment: That would be great!

Comment: See the edit, please